# Environment variables not available in getServerSideProps in Next.js 13 standalone build

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, typescript, next.js

I'm running into an issue where my pages aren't getting their props hydrated. I'm migrating from an older version of NextJS and this is where I'm stuck at the moment. Things work in dev or running `next start`, but once I use the standalone build, my values are undefined.

next.config.js has: output: "standalone"

myapp/pages/health.tsx

```
export async function getServerSideProps() {
    console.log(process.env.SOME_VALUE) // this is undefined in the server console
    return {
        props: {
            someValue: process.env.SOME_VALUE || '',
        },
    }
}
```

One path that temporarily worked was using getStaticProps() instead of getServerSideProps, however, this broke at dynamic routes (ex. [id].tsx, where I don't know all the IDs in advance to define in getStaticPaths, and even with 'blocking' set on fallback, would run into the undefined error again).

I've read the docs on environment variables in Next.js extensively, and these values should be available in getServerSideProps.

I know I can update these env vars to have NEXT_PUBLIC prefixes, but I'm wondering why this doesn't work in getServerSideProps.

Answer (score 0):

See if you have both .env and .env.local files in your directory